# Creating a web based expert system using Prolog

Tags: prolog, expert-system

I'm trying to create a web based expert system using prolog for a school project. i know how to use prolog but have no idea how it can be uploaded on the web. Does anyone have any idea how i can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

With swi you can build a web application directly:

http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/

Or you could use swish

http://swish.swi-prolog.org/

Or Pengines

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/pengines.html%27)

Comment: the tutorial here http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/ explain how to create web apps. i am trying to create an expert system that will be used on the web ie accessing the knowledge base and then be able to query that knowlegde base. please do you have any idea how i can accomplish that?

Comment: If its an expert system that is on the web then surely that is a web app..